# How to improve this code for binary search in doubly linked list

Tags: java, binary-search, doubly-linked-list

I have written the following code for binary search of a doubly-linked list. The question allows me to only use three pointers (for searching part). I have tried to implement the binary search process for array in this, and have successfully searched the position of the no. in the list. But, I am a bit concerned about the loop condition. It will not work in case if all (or some) the input no. are same. If anyone can suggest a better loop condition, it would be much appreciated. Also, if anyone can suggest any improvement in certain areas of this code, it would be appreciated as well.

```
class LL_Bin_search
{
    public static void main()
    {
        int c=1,pos=1;
        Scanner ob= new Scanner(System.in);
        A home= new A();
        A node=home;
        home.next=null;
        home.previous= null;
        System.out.println("Enter no.");
        home.x= ob.nextInt();
        A mp=home;
        for(;home.x!=0;)
        {
            int v= ob.nextInt();
            if(v==0)
                break;
            A node1 = new A();
            node1.x =v;
            node.next =node1;
            node1.previous= node;
            node1.next =null;
            node= node1;
            if(c++%2==0)
            {
                pos++;
                mp=mp.next;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Midpos is"+pos+"of"+mp.x);
        A fp=home;
        c=c/2;
        System.out.println("Enter value to be searched");
        int value= ob.nextInt();
        int f=0;
        for(;fp.x<node.x;)
        {
            c=c/2;
            if(mp.x==value)
            {
                System.out.println(pos);
                f=1;
                break;

            }
            else if(mp.x<value)
            {
                fp =mp.next;
                for(int i= 0;i<c;i++)
                {
                    mp=mp.next;
                    pos++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                node=node.previous;
                for(int i=0;i<=c;i++)
                {
                    mp=mp.previous;
                    pos--;
                }
            }
        }
        if(f==0)
        {
            System.out.println("Value not present");
        }
    }
}
class A
{
    int x;
    A next;
    A previous;
}
```

Comment: When you run this with a debugger, what is the first thing to go wrong when you have duplicate values?

Comment: If I enter the same values, and if I search that value, it will show that value is not present

Comment: That is the *last* thing to go wrong; what is the *first* thing to go wrong?

Comment: @Scott I suspect that is the first thing, that's the only problem I have encountered

Comment: @Scott I don't have debugger; I am just a noob programmer

Comment: If you aren't programming in an IDE with a debugger then you better have a good reason there buddy. Start familiarizing yourself with the tools available to programmers asap. Also, while you're fresh, try to learn and build a habit of good programming practices, such as following good naming conventions: `A` is not a good name for a class, `Node` or something would be much better.

Comment: umm, thanks, but does BlueJ have a debugger? I don't know that yet